# Android Studio ProGuard IOException

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to obfuscate the code, but getting error like

> Error:Execution failed for task ':lavasa-android-lib:proguardRelease'.
>    java.io.IOException: Can't read [E:\kumar-backup\Home\Untitled Folder\StudioWorkSpace\Lavasa\lavasa-android-lib\bin\classes] (No such file or directory)

Build. gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.rba.example"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles  'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':lavasa-android-lib')
}
```

proguard-rules.pro:

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-injars      com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
-injars      com.rba.ui:materialdesignlibrary:0.1.5
-injars      com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1
-libraryjars E:\kumar-backup\Home\Untitled Folder\StudioWorkSpace\Lavasa\lavasa-android-lib\libs\js.jar
-libraryjars /usr/local/java/android-sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

Note : I followed the below link, eventhough getting error.

[Android Studio - ProGuard "java.io.IOException ...bin\classes (No such file or directory)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028171/android-studio-proguard-java-io-ioexception-bin-classes-no-such-file-or-d)

Comment: Does the directory bin/classes exist ? for the submodule also ?

Comment: remove -injars & -libjars from the rules file since android gradle system automatically sets for you

Comment: i didn't get  you ramanadeep... can you please explain briefly..

Comment: if i remove -injars & libjars,it gives warnings like need to add missing jars..